# optimising the search time in hashmap

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

I have a csv file which is hashmapped, whenever the user enter the city name(key) it will display all the details of that city. I have to optimize the search result time, everytime the it is reading the file(instead of only once) and displaying the values.
The CSV files contains data like this :

> city,city_ascii,lat,lng,country,iso2,iso3,admin_name,capital,population,id
>   Malishevë,Malisheve,42.4822,20.7458,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Malishevë,admin,,1901597212
>   Prizren,Prizren,42.2139,20.7397,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Prizren,admin,,1901360309
>   Zubin Potok,Zubin Potok,42.9144,20.6897,Kosovo,XK,XKS,Zubin
>   Potok,admin,,1901608808

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
public class CSVFileReaders{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "C:\\worldcities1.csv";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);                                      
    System.out.println(" \n Enter the City name to be Searched :   \n _> ");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String searchTerm = in.nextLine();
    readAndFindRecordFromCSV(filePath, searchTerm);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    System.out.println(" \n It took " + (end - start) + " Milli Seconds to search the result \n");
    in.close();
}

public static void readAndFindRecordFromCSV( String filePath, String searchTerm) {
    try{            
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> cityMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();        
        Scanner x = new Scanner (new File(filePath),"UTF-8");
        String city= "";
        while(x.hasNextLine()) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        String name  = x.nextLine();
        //break each line of the csv file to its elements
        String[] line = name.split(",");
        city = line[1];
            for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
                values.add(line[i]);            
            }
        cityMap.put(city,values);       
        }
        x.close();
        //Search the city
        if(cityMap.containsKey(searchTerm)) {

                System.out.println("City name is : "+searchTerm+"\nCity details are accordingly in the order :"
                                    + "\n[city , city_ascii , lat , lng , country , iso2 , iso3 , admin_name , capital , population , id] \n"
                                    +cityMap.get(searchTerm)+"");

            }           
        else {
            System.out.println("Enter the correct City name");
        }                       
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

the time should be optimized and every time i search it is reading the entire file(which should happen)

Comment: 1) Why do you have to read the file for every search. 2) you can just just drop the hashmap and check if `line[1].equals(searchTerm)` which directly gives you all the city info you need, which allows you to stop iterating and directly printing out the infos

Comment: I would suggest you get something like SQLLite and just put the CSV in a small database. Then you can run optimized search queries against the database without having to rebuild everytime your app starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you mix the map initialization inside the search function.
You don't want that.
First, init the map, then use it in the search function.
To do that, extract a method for statements that instantiate and value the map and then refactor the `readAndFindRecordFromCSV()` method so that it accepts a `Map` as additional parameter :

```
 public static void readAndFindRecordFromCSV( String filePath, String searchTerm,  HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> dataByCity) {...}
```

With refactoring IDE features, it should be simple enough : "extracting method" then "change signature".

Here is a code (not tested at runtime but tested at compile time) that splits the logical in separated tasks and also rely on instance methods :

```
public class CSVFileReaders {

    private final String csvFile;
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> cityMap;
    private final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "C:\\worldcities1.csv";
        CSVFileReaders csvFileReaders = new CSVFileReaders(filePath);
        csvFileReaders.createCitiesMap();
        csvFileReaders.processUserFindRequest(); // First search
        csvFileReaders.processUserFindRequest(); // Second search
    }


    public CSVFileReaders(String csvFile) {
        this.csvFile = csvFile;
    }

    public void createCitiesMap() {
        cityMap = new HashMap<>();
        try (Scanner x = new Scanner(new File(csvFile), "UTF-8")) {
            String city = "";
            while (x.hasNextLine()) {
                ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
                String name = x.nextLine();
                //break each line of the csv file to its elements
                String[] line = name.split(",");
                city = line[1];
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                    values.add(line[i]);
                }
                cityMap.put(city, values);
            }
            x.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public void processUserFindRequest() {

        System.out.println(" \n Enter the City name to be Searched :   \n _> ");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String searchTerm = in.nextLine();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(" \n It took " + (end - start) + " Milli Seconds to search the result \n");
        //Search the city
        if (cityMap.containsKey(searchTerm)) {
            System.out.println("City name is : " + searchTerm + "\nCity details are accordingly in the order :"
                                       + "\n[city , city_ascii , lat , lng , country , iso2 , iso3 , admin_name , capital , population , id] \n"
                                       + cityMap.get(searchTerm) + "");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter the correct City name");
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting part is here :

```
String filePath = "C:\\worldcities1.csv";
CSVFileReaders csvFileReaders = new CSVFileReaders(filePath);
csvFileReaders.createCitiesMap();
csvFileReaders.processUserFindRequest(); // First search
csvFileReaders.processUserFindRequest(); // Second search
```

The logical is clearer now.

Comment: Maybe even better, make it a java class, the map is initialized as a member, the csv is provided via the constructor and the search method is not static anymore -> voila basic OO :)

Comment: @Lino Absolutely agreed.

Comment: @Lino can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Why do you create / load the CSV into a HashMap with every search ? 
Just create the HashMap **only once in the beginning**, and then on every search just check whether it exists in the HashMap, eg move the read part into a separate method :

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> cityMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(); 

public static void readCSVIntoHashMap( String filePath) {
    try{            

        Scanner x = new Scanner (new File(filePath),"UTF-8");
        String city= "";
        while(x.hasNextLine()) {
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        String name  = x.nextLine();
        //break each line of the csv file to its elements
        String[] line = name.split(",");
        city = line[1];
            for(int i=0;i<line.length;i++){
                values.add(line[i]);            
            }
        cityMap.put(city,values);       
        }
        x.close();
    ...
    }
```

Then have a separate method for searching :

```
public static void search(String searchTerm) {
  if(cityMap.containsKey(searchTerm)) {
  ...
}
}
```

Comment: Asking _questions_ is never an _answer_.

Comment: This is well suited as a comment and not as an answer

Comment: @funkyjelly if I create a separate method its showing, cityMap cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @raks Just declare it as an instance variable (ie move declaration outside the read method). See updated answer.